# AWS Lambda Python/R rpy2 issue: "Unable to import module 'py_test': No module named 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface'"

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rpy2

Firstly, I'm a newbie R, AWS and python guy.  So I'm trying to get a python script with embedded R code running in AWS Lambda using rpy2.  I created a Lambda package on an EC2 instance following the instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) (modified for using python 3.4).  The script runs fine in the EC2 virtual environment, but when uploaded to AWS and tested I receive the error:

*Unable to import module 'py_test': No module named 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface'*

The test file (*py_test.py*) looks like this (as you can see I've tried various things to try to get the rpy2 module included etc):

```
import os

os.environ["R_HOME"] = os.getcwd()
os.environ["R_USER"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'rpy2')
os.environ["R_LIBS"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'library')
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lib')

import sys  
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'rpy2'))

import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects

def test_handler(event, context):
    robjects.r('''
        f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
            if (verbose) {
                cat("I am calling f().\n")
            }
            2 * pi * r
        }
        print(f(3))
        ''')

test_handler(None,None)
```

I'm not sure on those environment variables, but that's what I found on the interwebs.  I have scoured google looking for answers but have come up empty.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe rpy2 is available to import directly like that from lambda.

You'll need to install rpy2 in a directory with the code and zip and load the zip file to AWS.

See this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

EDIT

Okay. It appears you're missing some of the steps from the tutorial that you linked. Make sure to load R shared libraries from lib dir and make sure the lambda_handler function is has the same general functionality.

Comment: Yes I did do that.  That script is inside a package with all the necessary R libraries, rpy2 etc as per the link included which goes throught the process of setting up a python/R lambda package.

Comment: Ah yeah when I try to load the libs using ctypes, I get the error "OSError: lib/libRrefblas.so: undefined symbol: xerbla_".  That should have been mentioned which I was also unable to resolve. :-/